# I am not getting desired output for this C program

Tags: c, arrays, c-preprocessor

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define TOTAL_NO (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
int array[]={23,34,12,17,204,99,16};

int main()
{         


int d;
for(d=-1; d<=(TOTAL_NO-2); d++)
printf("%d\n",array[d+1]);

return 0;

}
```

Why is this program not displaying contents of array?
Where is the bug?

Comment: Why not `for(d = 0; d < TOTAL_NO; d++) printf("%d\n", array[d]);`?

Comment: sizeof(int) returns an unsingned int. or size_t structure,which contains an uint32_t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TOTAL_NO` returns a value with type `size_t`.  This is unsigned so `d` gets converted to unsigned for the test `d<=(TOTAL_NO-2)` in the loop exit condition.

Assuming 32-bit integers, this makes the initial test

```
0xffffffff <= 7
```

This obviously fails, preventing the loop from running.

The loop runs as you expect if you change this to

```
for(d=-1; d<=(int)(TOTAL_NO-2); d++)
```

Changing your loop to the more normal form

```
for(d=0; d<TOTAL_NO; d++)
```

would work too.  This is preferable as it results in clearer, more maintainable code

Comment: yes now its working fine, i forgot that sizeof produces an unsigned integer value. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use macro is more better

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define TOTAL_NO(X) (sizeof(X) / sizeof(X[0])) 


int array[10]={23,34,12,17,204,99,16};

int main()
{         


int d;
for(d = -1; d <= (int)TOTAL_NO(array); d++) {
 printf(" %d\n",array[d+1]);

}
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should know sizeof returns type size_t,and d is type int,when you put them together,type of d will become to unsigned,and d will turn to a large number.like below code:

```
int a=-1;
unsigned b=1;
if(b>a)
    //something will never run
```